# How to add only close button to right corner of chromeapp

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-app

I am new to chrome app development. I have searched through many reference but I couldn't find a way to add close button to chrome app as we can see in postman or in browser.

I have read this [doc](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app.window#type-CreateWindowOptions), but I am not able to write code.
Can some one please tell me how to add those buttons.

Answer (score 0):

In createWindowOptions their is one attribute as frame by default it is set chrome.
I have set that option as none so that's why basic browser button like close, minimize and maximize was not visible.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend making your own frame and using a frameless window. Here is an example of it: [Frameless Window Sample on Github](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/frameless-window)

Otherwise, if you're ok with having the minimize and close buttons, you can set a min and max for width and height. This will get rid of the maximize button.

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function(launchData) {
  chrome.app.window.create(
    'index.html',
    {
      id: 'mainWindow',
      bounds: {width: 800, height: 600},
      maxWidth: 800, 
      maxHeight: 600
    }
  );
});
```